# Две секции в so

Tags: elf, linux

У меня есть две секции в подгружаемой библиотечке: в первой из секций проводятся манипуляции, необходимые для работы второй секции. Вызывающее приложение сначала дергает функцию из первой секции, потом функции из другой секции. Вопрос: дергает ли загрузчик что-нибудь из второй секции до того, как внешнее приложение обратиться к первой секции?

Answer (score 1):

C++ рантайм может вызывать конструкторы статических переменных в секциях кода(.text). Порядок вызова соответственно не определен.